# Derivative of matrix exponential with two matrices

Tags: calculus, matrices, lie-algebras, matrix-calculus

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are non-commuting matrices and $t$ is a real parameter.
Is the $t$-derivative of the matrix exponential $e^{A + t B}$ equal to the matrix $B \,e^{A+tB}$? Or is this not true due to Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff? Relatedly, is it true that the $t$-derivative at $t=0$ is given by
$$
\frac{d^n}{dt^n} e^{A+tB} \mid_{t=0}\,\stackrel{?}{=} B^n e^A
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Here is a counter-example. Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then you can explicitly calculate
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt}e^{A+tB}\right|_{t=0}=\begin{pmatrix}0&e-1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},
$$
while
$$
B\,e^A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$